# How function signature matches requested types

Tags: haskell, type-inference

Im trying to understand how this works; In GHCi:

```
foldMap (+3) (Just 5) :: Sum Int
```

produce result

```
Sum {getSum = 8}
```

Now, type of foldMap is

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

and from that type signatures for function used by foldMap do not match with signature of used function (+3):

```
(+3) :: Num a => a -> a
```

vs

```
f :: Monoid m => a -> m
```

If I also try something like this:

```
foldMap _ (Just 5) :: Sum Int
---------------------------------------
<interactive>:113:9: error:  
* Found hole: _ :: Integer -> Sum Int  
* In the first argument of `foldMap', namely `_'  
  In the expression: foldMap _ (Just 5) :: Sum Int  
....
```

this also show that expected function is of signature `:: (Integer -> Sum Int)` and which is consistent with signature in foldMap declaration but not consistent with (+3) which is used  above? My understanding of foldMap is that it apply function which turn every element of Foldable instance into Monoid which is then possible to collapse into single values.

I assume that compiler infere what types should be (in line above it is explicitly stated) but what I don't understand is how does compiler "adjust" types signature of function (+3) so that first line compile?

Comment: Well `instance Num a => Num (Sum a)` holds, so that means that `5` is a `Sum Int`.

Comment: Yikes, "Found hole: `_ :: Integer -> Sum Int`" is incredibly misleading! It should actually be something like "Found hole: `_ :: exists a. Num a *> a -> Sum Int`", but `exists` (the dual of `forall`) and `(*>)` (the dual of `(=>)`) don't exist in Haskell (yet?). Defaulting chose `a ~ Integer`, but other choices are valid, too, including in particular `Sum Int`, so another valid type for that hole is `Sum Int -> Sum Int` -- and `(+3)` can indeed be given that type.

Comment: @DanielWagner I get `Found hole: _ :: a0 -> Sum Int` after disabling defaulting. And then `Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘5’ prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved.` Not too shabby. The default version is indeed yikes-worthy.

Comment: @chi Ah, nice, I had tried `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, since that's the *usual* culprit for defaulting, which didn't help; I didn't think to try `default ()`, but once I read your comment it was clear that was the way to go, and that collection of errors does look much better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In short**: since `instance Num a => Num (Sum a)` holds, your `5` is seen as a `Sum Int`.

Given `a` is a `Num` type, `Sum a`, is a `Num` type as well. Indeed, in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) we see:

> ```
> Num a => Num (Sum a)
> ```

Now a `Num` type `n` has a function `fromInteger :: Integer -> n` to transform an `Integer` into that number type `n`. The idea is that if you thus write `5`, you implicitly write something like `fromInteger 5`.

By writing

```
foldMap (+3) (Just 5) :: Sum Int
```

with [**`foldMap :: (Foldable f, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap) we thus know that `m` should be a `Sum Int`, that `t ~ Maybe`, and since `(+3) :: Num a => a -> a`, it means that `m ~ a ~ Sum Int`. It thus means that the `5` (from `Just 5`) and `3` (from `(+3)`) are `Sum Int`s. The `5` you have written is thus interpreted as a `Sum 5`. The same holds for `3`.

So now that we know that we actually have written:

```
foldMap (+ (Sum 3)) (Just (Sum 5)) :: Sum Int
```

The `foldMap` will map every element of the structure to a monoid (well it is already a monoid, but it will increment them with `3` anyway), and then perform a fold. So that means we have written something like:

```
(+ (Sum 3)) (Sum 5) <> mempty
```

For the `Num n => Sum n` types the `mempty` is `Sum 0`, so that means we wrote:

```
(+ (Sum 3)) (Sum 5) <> (Sum 0)
```

and `(<>)` for a `Sum` is the `(+)`, so it means the expression boils down to:

```
(+ (Sum 3)) (Sum 5) + (Sum 0)
```

which can be evaluated to:

```
(Sum 5 + Sum 3) + Sum 0
```

or:

```
Sum 8
```

Comment: Uff! I was not aware that compiler will run `fromInteger` function trying to adjust 3 and 5 into something that will allow signatures to match and compile; that makes it understandable now, thanks!

Comment: @simkestuff You don't really need to be aware that `fromInteger` is how the compiler does it (unless you're writing your own `Num` instances), but you do need to know that numeric literals like `3` and `5` can be interpreted as many different types. The interpretation the compiler chooses depends on the context you use them in, so unfortunately when you change the code to get more information as in your question with the hole, then you might change what types the numbers are and get misleading information.